# Const references with and without type conversion - why feature type conversion at all? - C++

Tags: c++, type-conversion, const-reference

I began learning C++ this week, and currently I am reading about compound types and constant variables. Unlike in most cases, references to `const` support type conversion by creating a temporary variable. But if so, then what's the difference in behaviour between:

```
int i = 42;
double di = 42;
```

and

```
int i = 42;
const double &di = 42;
```

Don't we end up with two independent variables that can end up having different values if we try to change `i`? Is the only difference that in the example with the const reference, the reference cannot be changed? The thing that bugs me the most is that when the types of a non-`const` variable and a `const` ref match, the reference points to the same address in memory and changes along with the change in the original variable, whereas this does not happen for a non-typematching `const` ref to a non-`const` variable:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int i = 42;
    const int &ri = i;
    const double &dri = i;
    
    ++i;
    std::cout << " at " << &i << ", " << ri << " at "
              << &ri << ", " << dri << " at " << &dri << std::endl;

    int j = i;
    int jj = ri;
    int djj = dri;
    std::cout << j << " at " << &j << ", " << jj << " at "
              << &jj << ", " << djj << " at " << &dri << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
43 at %Address1%, 43 at %Address1%, 42 at %Address2%
43 at %Address3%, 43 at %Address4%, 42 at %Address2%
```

This seems to me like a major difference in behavior that is easy to overlook from simply looking at the syntax, on top of the fact that such behavior seems counter-intuitive to the entire idea of references. Also, why does `jj` is allocated a separate space, but not `djj`, which references the same address as `dri`?

Comment: "*This seems to me like a major difference in behavior that is easy to overlook from simply looking at the syntax*" Um... why? Do you think we frequently care about the address of random variables? "*not djj, which references the same address as dri?*" No, it doesn't.

Comment: *"This seems to me like a major difference in behavior that is easy to overlook from simply looking at the syntax"* -- so don't do it. Problem solved? *I think you are applying a concept to a single, specific scenario without considering what could happen in other scenarios. Then when that single scenario does not work out well for your tastes, you think the concept should be dumped, even for the scenarios you did not consider.*

Comment: *"but not `djj`, which references the same address as `dri`?"* -- it does not. Copy-paste error in your code? You output `djj` then the address of `dri`, instead of the address of `djj`.

Comment: Speaking of typos in your code, isn't `std::cout << " at " << &i <<` supposed to be `std::cout << i << " at " << &i <<`?

Comment: To be fair, I can't imagine this being an issue. You don't normally write code like this, you don't use two references (names) to one variable within single scope. You either use reference to pass view of the variable to another function or you use it to shorten a long syntax (including for loops). When you create reference, you don't use the original name, because the point of creating a reference is to skip the original name (for whatever reason).

Comment: @JaMiT, yes, sorry, there was a typo in my code! A variable simply registers a copy of the value provided, as expected for the line `int djj = dri;`. As for my question, it's not so much about "let's get rid of that", it's more about "can you please show me scenarios that illustrate why this makes sense"

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Yeah, I am more puzzled by the very idea of referencing a variable of another type: if you change the original variable, the link between that and the reference is lost. Why even refer to such a case as reference at all? What's the difference in behavior between `const double &dri = i;` and `const double dri = i;`?

Comment: @OlegShevchenko *"there was a typo in my code!"* -- not just "was", but still is. Please edit your question to fix the typos.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you have a function of the form:

```
void foo(double const& d);
```

And now, let's say you have a `float` somewhere. And you want to pass that to this function via `foo(f);`. If a `T const&` could not bind to any object convertible to `T`, then this wouldn't work. Every user of this function that don't have a `double` would have to do `foo(static_cast<double>(f))` or an equivalent.

You might say that maybe `foo` should take `double` by value. And for `double` specifically, maybe it should.

But what about if it's `std::string`, and I want to call `foo("some string")`. Well, `"some string"` is not a `std::string`; it is a string literal which is *convertible* to `std::string`. So we allow that conversion.

Again, you might say that it should take the `string` by value. But what about the cases when the caller *really does* have a `std::string`? They'd have to *copy* that string, a copy that is discarded and is therefore unnecessary.

Of course, C++'s rules should be uniform. So if we want this to work for function arguments&parameters, it also has to work for named variables. But even then, it could be useful. You might call a function that you expect to return a string of some form, but aren't especially picky about which form. Just so long as it is convertible to a `std::string`. This might be in template code:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T t)
{
  std::string const& data = t.get_a_string();
}
```

Do you really care if `get_a_string` returns `std::string` exactly, or just some string type *convertible* to `std::string`? Probably the latter.